# Create graph Editor

Tags: java, graph

I want to create a graph editor written in Java.

In this editor I want the possibility that nodes can contain other nodes.
The possibility to define a palette with object, and the possibility to define object 
in the palette at runtime.

I'm starting with GMF in Eclipse but I've some doubt, is it better to use JUNG2 or something else?

Comment: To a question this open, the only answer can be: It depends! Provide us with more info, especially your doubts and what you have tried, and maybe we can help.

Comment: at the first look GMF is very powerful but doesn't appear too much mantained, maybe it's only a bad impression. After the creation of the graph the tool will provide some code. The similar thing to the graph is a graph of logic port and wire where I want to save some part of the circuit for reuse, put them in palette for reuse.

Comment: I'm going to try JGraphX

Answer (score 2):

I used [JGraphX](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) once, it's very nice and develops constantly. It provides all that you described (you can even find example with the pallete in downloaded package).